# f string within triple quotation string airflow

Tags: python, airflow, f-string

I am new to airflow and and am using `AwsLambdaInvokeFunctionOperator` in my code. The **OutputLocation** in **payload** is a variable `S3` path with **name** as variable which i tried to achieve using `fstring` but that didn't work.
Could someone please guide me how i can use variable name in the path in payload.

```
client=boto3.Session().client('ssm')

NAME=client.get_parameter(
     Name='name',
     WithDecryption=True
 )['Parameter']['Value']
```

```
test_lambda = AwsLambdaInvokeFunctionOperator(
    region_name='ap-southeast-1',
    check_success_function=lambda_pass,
    task_id="test_lambda",
    function_name='test-function',
    awslogs_group="/airflow/lambda/{0}".format('test-function'),
    payload="""{
                "AthenaOut":{"QueryExecution": {"ResultConfiguration": {"OutputLocation": 
                f"s3://datasource/test/{name}/output/result.csv" }}},
                "primary_keys":["id"],
                "table": "student",
                 "schema": "public" 
              }""",
    dag=dag,
    depends_on_past=False,
    wait_for_downstream=False,
)
```

Comment: First of all please elaborate on *"but that didnt work"*. You should provide a [mre] of the code and errors. Second, I don't see f-strings anywhere in your code...

Comment: @Tomerikoo: It's there, embedded in the triple quote string, about halfway down the second code block.

Answer (score 2):

You either have to split it up into multiple smaller strings, one of which is an f-string:

```
payload= '{' \
                + '"AthenaOut":{"QueryExecution": {"ResultConfiguration": {"OutputLocation": ' \
                + f'"s3://datasource/test/{name}/output/result.csv"' \
                + ' }}},' \
                + '"primary_keys":["id"],' \
                + '"table": "student",' \
                + ' "schema": "public" ' \
              + '}'
```

or you need to make the entire triple-quote an f-string, which will require escaping all your curly brackets (a double curly bracket `{{` is a literal curly bracket in an f-string):

```
payload=f"""{{
                "AthenaOut":{{"QueryExecution": {{"ResultConfiguration": {{"OutputLocation": 
                "s3://datasource/test/{name}/output/result.csv" }}}}}},
                "primary_keys":["id"],
                "table": "student",
                 "schema": "public" 
              }}"""
```

Note the syntax highlighting in the above code blocks. The 'inserted' parts of the f-strings are in black, while the 'regular' string parts are in green.

Answer (score -1):

How about *not* writing that as a string?

```
payload=json.dumps({
    "AthenaOut": {
        "QueryExecution": {
            "ResultConfiguration": {
                "OutputLocation": f"s3://datasource/test/{name}/output/result.csv"
            }
        }
    },
    "primary_keys": ["id"],
    "table": "student",
    "schema": "public",
}),
```